# What will be the output and why ArrayList/ any Collection behave like this?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Say below is my bean class:

```
public class Employee {

    private String name = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This is my main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName("First name");

        ArrayList<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList.add(employee);

        employee.setName("Last name");

        for (Employee emp : empList) {
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

When I executed the output is: `Last name`

**My question is:**

1. As I know Java is [*pass-by-value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) or rather
   [*pass-by-copy-of-the-variable-value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value#7034719) then does the copy of
   `employee` object was saved in the ArrayList or it references the
   original object of Employee as the object value is getting changed
   to `Last name` after adding to `ArrayList`?
2. Does every Collection behave this way?

Comment: when a primitive is passed to a function it is passed-by-value, when an object is passed to a function the reference to said object is passed-by-value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A copy of the `employee` reference was saved in the `ArrayList`, but since it refers to the same `Employee` instance, changing the instance later via the `employee` reference affects the element stored in the `ArrayList`.

Yes, every `Collection` behaves this way, since the `Collection`s don't create copies of the instances passed to them, they just store references to those instances.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. As I know Java is pass-by-value or rather pass-by-copy-of-the-variable-value then does the copy of employee
>      object was saved in the ArrayList or it references the original object
>      of Employee as the object value is getting changed to Last name after
>      adding to ArrayList?

The reference will be *passed-by-value*. So, there will be 2 references pointing to the same Employee instance. One reference is `employee` and another is in the `arraylist`.

> 2. Does every Collection behave this way?

Yes. Actually, this is *NOT* a property of collections. This is the way java was designed. All *mutable* reference types behave in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `employee` and the first element of the list are two **different** references to **the same object**. That's why modifying the referenced object (via `setName`, for example) on one of them will be visible via the other.

However, if you replace the reference by assigning a different one, it **will not** effect the other.

E.g.:

```
employee = new Employee();
employee.setName("Vishrant");
```

Now `employee` and the first element of the list reference **different** objects, so the element in the array will not be called `"Vishrant"`.